What is the limit of $\frac{x^2-y^2}{\cos(x) - \cos(y)}$as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$
I tried to plug in $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ and they both get $-2$ but I was wondering how I could prove it. By looking at the graph it is $-2$. But I do not know how to prove that it is. I tried squeeze but I don't know how to make it work.

HINT
Notice that $x^{2} - y^{2} = (x - y)(x + y)$ as well as
\begin{align*}
\cos(x) - \cos(y) = -2\sin\left(\frac{x - y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

$$\begin{align*}\lim_{\left( x,y \right) \rightarrow \left( 0,0 \right)} \frac{x^2-y^2}{\cos x-\cos y}=&\lim_{\left( x,y \right) \rightarrow \left( 0,0 \right)} \frac{x^2-y^2}{-2\sin \frac{x+y}{2}\sin \frac{x-y}{2}}\\=&-2\lim_{\left( x,y \right) \rightarrow \left( 0,0 \right)} \frac{\frac{x+y}{2}\frac{x-y}{2}}{\sin \frac{x+y}{2}\sin \frac{x-y}{2}}\\=&-2\lim_{\left( x,y \right) \rightarrow \left( 0,0 \right)} \left( \frac{\frac{x+y}{2}}{\sin \frac{x+y}{2}}\cdot \frac{\frac{x-y}{2}}{\sin \frac{x-y}{2}} \right) \\=&-2\end{align*}$$
